# How to check whether a string is a valid HTTP URL?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, url, uri

There are the [`Uri.IsWellFormedUriString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Uri.TryCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131572.aspx) methods, but they seem to return `true` for file paths, etc.

How do I check whether a string is a valid (not necessarily active) HTTP URL for input validation purposes?

Comment: Do not use regex.IsMatch at all to validate Url.
Can kill cpu.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227785/why-does-checking-this-string-with-regex-ismatch-cause-cpu-to-reach-100

Answer (score 614, accepted):

Try this to validate HTTP URLs (`uriName` is the URI you want to test):

```
Uri uriResult;
bool result = Uri.TryCreate(uriName, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) 
    && uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp;
```

Or, if you want to accept both HTTP and HTTPS URLs as valid (per J0e3gan's comment):

```
Uri uriResult;
bool result = Uri.TryCreate(uriName, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) 
    && (uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps);
```

Comment: Should this read uriResult.Scheme instead of uriName.Scheme? I'm using the overload to TryCreate that takes String instead of Uri as it's first parameter.

Comment: You may want to add more conditions to the uriResult.Scheme == ... Specifically https. It depends on what you need this for, but this small change was all I needed for it to work perfectly for me.

Comment: To be clear per @Fiarr's comment, the "small change" needed to account for HTTPS in addition to HTTP URLs is: `bool result = Uri.TryCreate(uriName, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) && uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps;`

Comment: Here's an extension method for a string which does all the above:         public static bool IsUrl(this string str)
        {
            Uri uriResult;
            bool result = Uri.TryCreate(str, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) && (uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps);
            return result;
        }

Comment: What if url contains hashbang?

Comment: jon schneider has incorporated j0e3gan's comment into the answer posted here.

Comment: this way fails for URL like _http://abcde_. It says this is a valid URL.

Comment: @KailashP a URL in that format could indeed be valid, for example on my company's intranet http://devinfo takes me to a sharepoint page

Comment: If the URL is deemed to be a relative URL, accessing `uriResult.Scheme` will throw an exception.

Comment: @JonathanWood In this case if a relative URL is passed in for 'uriName', 'Uri.TryCreate(uriName, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult)' will return false and 'uriResult.Scheme' will not be accessed, so no exception will be thrown.

Comment: What's the advantage over using Uri.IsWellFormedUriString, which is shorter?

Comment: Or in .NET Core, C#7 (where the constants in the Uri class are gone...):
`bool result = Uri.TryCreate(uriName, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri uriResult) 
    && (uriResult.Scheme == "http" || uriResult.Scheme == "https");`

Comment: @KailashP is right - I don't think I like this code without an extra check: `&& uriResult != null`!

Comment: Looks like this technique fails 22 out of 75 tests https://dotnetfiddle.net/XduN3A

Comment: @Lee what is the better option to test the url?

Comment: Does this mean - Url complies with RFC3986 ?

Comment: @whitneyland : Do you have any solution for this please ?

Comment: This approach says the following is a valid url `https://www.somesite.com/"><script>alert(0)</script>`  but if supplied by the user this definitely is NOT a "url" you'd want to put in the href of an html anchor tag. :-)

Comment: Although this technique fails 22 out of 75 tests as indicated in the dotnetfiddle link, what if instead of keeping the URL "as-is", you use `uriResult.AbsoluteUri` ?  I've found that many of the failed tests' URLs actually become valid URLs if you use the uriResult variable (it appears that Uri.TryCreate actually encodes spaces as %20 and < and > as %3C and %3E for you.

Answer (score 199):

This method works fine both in http and https. Just one line :)

```
if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("https://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute))
```

MSDN: [IsWellFormedUriString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: This will return true for non-HTTP URIs (i.e. [any other scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.scheme(v=vs.110).aspx) such as `file://` or `ldap://`.
This solution should be coupled with a check against the scheme - e.g. `if (uri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttp && uri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps) ...`

Comment: Is this RFC3986 compliant?

Comment: @Squiggle That's exactly what I want it to check, ***everything*** since I'm making a Downloader. So, this answer is the best method for me.

Comment: Problem is that IsWellFormedUriString renders spaces at the end as valid part of an URL. And no it don't thinks they are %20s, since adding a valid symbol after the spaces results in invalid URL:
"a" - valid
"a " - valid ?!
"a a" - invalid ?!?

Comment: For simple string URL validation, I think this is better, it simply returns false if you use "http:\\test.com" instead of "http://test.com" whereas `.TryCreate` is smart enough to correct the invalid slashes. But in my case this string was used elsewhere to make a REST call and caused an exception.

Comment: CAUTION: This will return `true` for url like `javascript:alert("xss")`

Answer (score 39):

Try that:

```
bool IsValidURL(string URL)
{
    string Pattern = @"^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$";
    Regex Rgx = new Regex(Pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return Rgx.IsMatch(URL);
}
```

It will accept URL like that:

- http(s)://www.example.com
- http(s)://stackoverflow.example.com
- http(s)://www.example.com/page
- http(s)://www.example.com/page?id=1&product=2
- http(s)://www.example.com/page#start
- http(s)://www.example.com:8080
- http(s)://127.0.0.1
- 127.0.0.1
- www.example.com
- example.com

Comment: Underrated comment right here.

Comment: http(s)://www.example.com/page  << example of URL consist of METHOD PROTOCOL (http(s)://)  + TYPE OF SERVER(www) + HOST NAME(example) + TOP LEVEL OF DOMAIN NAME (com) + PATH(page)

Answer (score 31):

```
    public static bool CheckURLValid(this string source)
    {
        Uri uriResult;
        return Uri.TryCreate(source, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) && uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp;
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
string url = "htts://adasd.xc.";
if(url.CheckUrlValid())
{
  //valid process
}
```

**UPDATE:** (single line of code) *Thanks @GoClimbColorado*

```
public static bool CheckURLValid(this string source) => Uri.TryCreate(source, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri uriResult) && uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
```

**Usage:**

```
string url = "htts://adasd.xc.";
if(url.CheckUrlValid())
{
  //valid process
}
```

Comment: This does not appear to handle www urls.  IE: www.google.com is shown as invalid.

Comment: @ZauberParacelsus "www.google.com" is invalid. URL mean should start with "http","ftp","file" etc. string should be "http:// www.google.com" without space

Comment: Today, the out parameter can make an improvement `Uri.TryCreate(source, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri uriResult) && uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps`

Comment: this doesnt work for random string like abc,tassdds etc..

Answer (score 21):

All the answers here either allow URLs with other schemes (e.g., `file://`, `ftp://`) or reject human-readable URLs that don't start with `http://` or `https://` (e.g., `www.google.com`) *which is not good when dealing with user inputs*.

**Here's how I do it:**

```
public static bool ValidHttpURL(string s, out Uri resultURI)
{
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^https?:\/\/", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        s = "http://" + s;

    if (Uri.TryCreate(s, UriKind.Absolute, out resultURI))
        return (resultURI.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || 
                resultURI.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps);

    return false;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
string[] inputs = new[] {
                          "https://www.google.com",
                          "http://www.google.com",
                          "www.google.com",
                          "google.com",
                          "javascript:alert('Hack me!')"
                        };
foreach (string s in inputs)
{
    Uri uriResult;
    bool result = ValidHttpURL(s, out uriResult);
    Console.WriteLine(result + "\t" + uriResult?.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

**Output:**

```
True    https://www.google.com/
True    http://www.google.com/
True    http://www.google.com/
True    http://google.com/
False
```

Comment: This lets through single words like "mooooooooo" but used in conjunction with Uri.IsWellFormedUriString could be good

Comment: @Epirocks That's a good point. The problem is that `http://mooooooooo` is, in fact, a valid Uri. Therefore, you can't check for `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString` after inserting "http://" and if you check for it before, anything that doesn't have a `Scheme` will be rejected. Maybe what can be done is we check for `s.Contains('.')` instead.

Comment: moooooo by itself doesn't look like a url as it has no protocol on it. What I did was take out your regex match call, and &&'ed it with IsWellFormedUriString as well.

Comment: @Epirocks Exactly! The problem is that if you use `IsWellFormedUriString` before adding the `http://`, you'll end up rejecting things like `google.com` and if you use it after adding the `http://`, it'll still return true for `http://mooooooooo`. That's why I suggested checking if the string contains a `.` instead.

Comment: that's fine for me anyway I don't want to accept a url without http or https on it. So I use IsWellFormedUriString  first, then use your function without regex.  bool bResult = (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(s, UriKind.Absolute) && ValidHttpURL(s, out uriResult)); Thanks

Comment: It's important to note that URL's like `htt://google.com` are accepted

Answer (score 7):

After `Uri.TryCreate` you can check `Uri.Scheme` to see if it HTTP(s).

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative approach to using a regex, this code uses `Uri.TryCreate` per the OP, but then also checks the result to ensure that its [Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.scheme?view=net-5.0) is one of http or https:

```
bool passed =
  Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri uriResult)
    && (uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp
      || uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps);
```

Comment: Your answer came in lower quality posts. Please provide some explanation even though your code is self explanatory.

Answer (score 3):

This would return bool:

```
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(a.GetAttribute("href"), UriKind.Absolute)
```

Comment: I think the OP specifically mentioned, he doesn't like  Uri.IsWellFormedUriString as it gives true for file paths. Do you have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

**Problem**: Valid URLs should include all of the following “prefixes”: https, http, www

- Url must contain http:// or https://
- Url may contain only one instance of www.
- Url Host name type must be Dns
- Url max length is 100

**Solution**:

```
public static bool IsValidUrl(string webSiteUrl)
{
   if (webSiteUrl.StartsWith("www."))
   {
       webSiteUrl = "http://" + webSiteUrl;
   }
        
   return Uri.TryCreate(webSiteUrl, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri uriResult)
            && (uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp
             || uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps) && uriResult.Host.Replace("www.", "").Split('.').Count() > 1 && uriResult.HostNameType == UriHostNameType.Dns && uriResult.Host.Length > uriResult.Host.LastIndexOf(".") + 1 && 100 >= webSiteUrl.Length;
}
```

**Validated with Unit Tests**

**Positive Unit Test**:

```
    [TestCase("http://www.example.com/")]
    [TestCase("https://www.example.com")]
    [TestCase("http://example.com")]
    [TestCase("https://example.com")]
    [TestCase("www.example.com")]
    public void IsValidUrlTest(string url)
    {
        bool result = UriHelper.IsValidUrl(url);

        Assert.AreEqual(result, true);
    }
```

**Negative Unit Test**:

```
    [TestCase("http.www.example.com")]
    [TestCase("http:www.example.com")]
    [TestCase("http:/www.example.com")]
    [TestCase("http://www.example.")]
    [TestCase("http://www.example..com")]
    [TestCase("https.www.example.com")]
    [TestCase("https:www.example.com")]
    [TestCase("https:/www.example.com")]
    [TestCase("http:/example.com")]
    [TestCase("https:/example.com")]
    public void IsInvalidUrlTest(string url)
    {
        bool result = UriHelper.IsValidUrl(url);

        Assert.AreEqual(result, false);
    }
```

**Note**: IsValidUrl method should not validate any relative url path like example.com

**See**:

[Should I Use Relative or Absolute URLs?](https://www.seoquake.com/blog/relative-or-absolute-urls/)

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri uri = null;
if (!Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out uri) || null == uri)
    return false;
else
    return true;
```

Here `url` is the string you have to test.

Comment: null == url check is horribly reduntant

Answer (score 0):

I've created this function to help me with URL validation, you can customize it as you like, note this is written in python3.10.6

```
def url_validator(url: str) -> bool:
    """
    use this func to filter out the urls to follow only valid urls
    :param: url
    :type: str
    :return: True if the passed url is valid otherwise return false
    :rtype: bool
    """

    #the following regex is copied from Django source code 
    # to validate a url using regax
    
    regex = re.compile(
        r"^(?:http|ftp)s?://"  # http:// or https://
        r"(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}\.?)|"  # domain...
        r"localhost|"  # localhost...
        r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})"  # ...or ip
        r"(?::\d+)?"  # optional port
        r"(?:/?|[/?]\S+)$",
        re.IGNORECASE,
    )


    blocked_sites: list[str] = []

    for site in blocked_sites:
        if site in url or site == url:
            return False

    # if none of the above then ensure that the url is valid and then return True otherwise return False
    if re.match(regex, url):
        return True

    return False
```