# 'System.UriFormatException' in HyperLink

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have some strings like this:

> www.example.com/sdWqaP
>
> twitter.com/sdfks

and want to assign them to a `HyperLink`

```
var hyperlink = new Hyperlink
{
   NavigateUri = new Uri(url),
   TargetName = "_blank",
};
```

if url starts with `http://` it works fine, otherwise throws a `UriFormatException`.

**Update**: urls like this `www.google.com` aren't valid `http` urls. isn't there a better way than `var url = "http://" + "www.google.com"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
var uri = new UriBuilder(s).Uri;
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y868d5wh(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public UriBuilder(
    string uri
)
// If uri does not specify a scheme, the scheme defaults to "http:".
```

Answer (score 1):

[Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.scheme%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (`http://` in your case) is mandatory part of `Uri` string. `UriFormatException` will be thrown if the scheme specified in uri string is not correctly formed according to [Uri.CheckSchemeName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.checkschemename%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method.

**[[MSDN : Uri Constructor (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6c2z492%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)]**.

I don't understand well what you mean *"better safer way"*. Appending scheme in uri string is common practice anyway.

Comment: thanks @har07. my url strings may not have `http://` as in example, and my question is how to append that scheme? isn't there a better way than `var url = "http://" + "www.google.com"`?

Answer (score 1):

Check your URL is valid and then assign to the URL

For validating a URL check the below link

[How to check whether a string is a valid HTTP URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578857/how-to-check-whether-a-string-is-a-valid-http-url)