# Why does checking this string with Regex.IsMatch cause CPU to reach 100%?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

When using `Regex.IsMatch` (C#, .Net 4.5) on a specific string, the CPU reaches 100%.

String:

```
https://www.facebook.com/CashKingPirates/photos/a.197028616990372.62904.196982426994991/1186500984709792/?type=1&permPage=1
```

Pattern:

```
^http(s)?://([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=])?$
```

Full code:

```
Regex.IsMatch("https://www.facebook.com/CashKingPirates/photos/a.197028616990372.62904.196982426994991/1186500984709792/?type=1&permPage=1",
                @"^http(s)?://([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=])?$");
```

I found that redacting the URL prevents this problem. Redacted URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/CashKingPirates/photos/a.197028616990372.62904.196982426994991/1186500984709792
```

But still very interested in understanding what causes this.

Comment: The regex match involves large number of backtracks. For more information read on [runaway regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Comment: Since you have not preceded the dots by backslashes, probably your regex is a very complicated version of `^http(s)?://.+$` (i.e. matches http:// or https:// followed by anything).

Comment: Why don't you use the URI class?

Comment: @SalmanA I actually changed from regex to URI.TryCreate after seeing the potential harm.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As nu11p01n73R pointed out, you have a lot backtracking with your regular expression. That’s because parts of your expression can all match the same thing, which gives the engine many choices it has to try before finding a result.

You can avoid this by changing the regular expression to make individual sections more specific. In your case, the cause is that you wanted to match a real dot but used the match-all character `.` instead. You should escape that to `\.`.

This should already reduce the backtracking need a lot and make it fast:

```
^http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=])?$
```

And if you want to actually match the original string, you need to add a quantifier to the character class at the end:

```
^http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]+)?$
                                           ↑
```

Comment: Thanks but the regex you suggested does not match the original string. It is fast though.

Comment: Indeed, this is the only and exact reason that causes the catastrophic backtracking: the dot is not escaped, is not seen as a literal character and can match anything. @Nir: note that this exactly answer your question. You can easily correct your pattern now.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to check http://regexr.com/ website, to test your regular expression.

**The corrected version of your regular expression is this:**

```
^(https?://(?:[\w]+\.?[\w]+)+[\w]/?)([\w\./]+)(\?[\w-=&%]+)?$
```

It also has 3 groups:

1. group1=Main url (for example: facebook.com)
2. group2=Sub urls (for example: /CashKingPirates/photos/a.197028616990372.62904.196982426994991/1186500984709792/
3. group3=Variables (for example: ?type=1&permPage=1)

**Also remember for checking actual character of dot (.) in your regular expression you must use \. not .**

Comment: I can't tell you the exact reason of his problem, but as far as I know [\w-]+ is completely unnecessary in his regular expression.

Comment: regxer specially designed for js which won't support lookbehinds.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex suffers for `catastrophic backtracking`.You can simply use

```
^http(s)?://([\w.-])+(/[\w ./?%&=-]+)*$
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cK4iV0/15

Comment: This is a poor solution that reduces the intention of the original regex.