# c# regex url validation

Tags: c#

I'm using below regex for url validation.

```
 public static readonly string UrlValidation = @"^((http|ftp|https|www)://)?([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?$";
```

But,if i input google..com.my, the result is valid, but actually is not. How to amend the regex to make it not valid if input 2 dots.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578857/how-to-check-whether-a-string-is-a-valid-http-url

Comment: I'm not sitting in front of an IDE but wouldn't this also allow www://www.google.com and stuff like that (or am I misreading it)?

Answer (score 3):

A regex is probably the wrong approach here. Instead, consider `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString`. See documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformedoriginalstring(v=vs.110).aspx). Be warned, however--this function validates a wide variety of URIs.

Answer (score 1):

This Url Regex string comparison webpage has proven very helpful to me:

https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

The **@diegoperini (502 chars)** regex string proved infallible through all the tests in the above link:

```
_^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$_iuS
```

Answer (score 0):

Try foolowing regex

```
 /(http|ftp|https)://[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?/
```

Reference : [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1160956/Regex-for-url-validation-in-Csharp)