# Check if X contains Y, and also check if Y has Z or W amount of characters behind/after it

Tags: c#, contains

```
string myString = www.stackoverflow.com
```

1. i need to check if myString ends with `.` and any 3 other characters after it, i would prefer to do it with the `EndsWith()` method but if that's not possible any other way will work.
2. How can i check if myString contains a `.` that has anything but `www` behind it (and i'd like to know how to check if it has any Y amount of characters before/after it),  i tried this

   ```
        if (!myString.Contains(".".StartsWith("www")) &&  myString.Contains("."))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
        }
   ```

But it gives an error saying it can't convert from bool to string, i also tried creating `dynamic dot = ".";` and using it in place of `"."` and even though it compiled it would still crash when i run it.

Comment: Use Regex.Match

Comment: `".".StartsWith("www")` returns a boolean value and when you pass it to `myString.Contains(...)` it gives you the error, because `.Contains(...)` expects a string to search for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a string is a valid HTTP URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578857/how-to-check-whether-a-string-is-a-valid-http-url)

Comment: You are running into [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295) and instead of asking how to validate web address asking about your attempted solution with string methods.

Comment: @Sinatr Yes but not fully, i still want to know how to do the things ive listed incase im not checking websites

Answer (score 0):

```
        string myString = "www.stackoverflow.com";

        var splittedString = (myString.Split('.'));

        if (splittedString[0] == "www")
        {
            ///before first occurrence of . has wwww
        }

        if (splittedString[splittedString.Length-1].Length == 3)
        {
            //has 3 characters after last .
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand the last part. The string is split into 3 halfs, shouldn't you have wrrote `if (splittedString[2].Length == 3)`? And how did you say `splittedString.Length` without specifying which cut ?

Comment: @Octavylon This certain string has two ., thus 3 parts. In general if you dont know how many dots the string has you must take the expression I wrote.

Comment: But how did u say `[splittedString.Length -1]` without specifying which part of the cut? How will it decide which cut?

Comment: @Octavylon Length-1 will always be the last cut

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to validate all website urls use **System.Uri**

```
string url = "www.helloWorld.com";
if(Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
  {
  //Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression:

```
            string input = "www.stackoverflow.com";
            int numOfChars = 13;
            Regex rex = new Regex($"www.[A-Za-z0-9]{{{numOfChars}}}.[A-Za-z]{{3}}");
            var res = rex.IsMatch(input); // res == true
```