# How can I create a form that allows only URL input?

Tags: c#, xaml, webbrowser-control

I am developing a web browser using C# and XAML.

I want to make system that when users enter texts or numbers other than the URL in a URL display form, the screen display remains the same, but only the inside of the form is automatically blanked out and ready to be reentered.
I know that I need to add something to the code below, but I don't know how.
Please help.

```
private void txtUrl_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            wbSample.Navigate(txtUrl.Text);

    }
```

Comment: Be careful when selecting tags! Don't just type one letter and press enter, actually *check* what tags are selected. That way you won't use the C language tag by mistake, instead of the proper C# language tag. Please [edit] your question to fix it.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37051246/13515911